# NSApplicationMain syntax

Tags: objective-c

I am Completely new to Objective C and Cocoa programming.

Why does NSApplicationMain not have syntax like

```
[target selector];
```

Why We call it like

```
NSApplicationMain();
```

Or is this syntax for some sort of global methods ?
I was thinking that all methods in objective-C are on objects, seems like this is one of those global methods, 
Seniors in objective-C Please shed some light.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective C, at least historically, has been an extension of C.

And if you look at any new app that you create from the templates in Xcode, "`NSApplicationMain()`" is called from a main.m or a main.c file.

This is a hook to instantiate the Objective C runtime for a Macintosh app, or [as the Apple documentation puts it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html), `NSApplicationMain` is:

> Called by the main function to create and run the application.

Also, it provides a nice way to bridge the traditional C main function's "`int argc, const char *argv[]`" parameters to a main function into an Objective C application.

Comment: Nitpick: it doesn't actually start the Objective-C runtime (the compiler inserts all that) but it does set up the Cocoa Foundation/AppKit objects, like NSApplication and NSRunLoop.